# Stripe "invalid integer" error (python/flask backend)

Tags: python, flask

Stripe requires the amount passed in to be an integer, in cents.

I multiply a float (that has 2 decimal places, max) by 100 (to cents) then cast it to be an int. I then pass this amount to Stripe's charge create function.

Customer is seeing an invalid integer error. 5749.0000000001.

Anyone seen anything like this? Tips on how to avoid this? I thought casting to int then passing the value would be fool proof..

```
amount = int(currentValourPrice - previousPaid)
amount = roundToTwo(chargeTaxIfCanada(current_user,amount))
amountToCharge = int(amount * to_cents)
... then in the charge fn...
 amount=amountToCharge
```

Comment: What did you try? Sure you explained it, how did you implement that?

Comment: I have a feeling you're doing something like `x = x * 100; int(x); create_change(x)`. Am I right? Remember, you need to assign the result of `int` to something, or it will have no effect. `x = x * 100; x = int(x); create_change(x)`

Comment: If you post some code we might be able to identify the problem.

Comment: I've added some of the code. chargeTaxIfCanada will return a float. It gets reduced to two decimal places by the roundToTwo fn.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting a similar error with django even after directly passing the variable with int()